# Cordova Exec blocked the main thread even after usage of CordovaInterface.getThreadPool()

Tags: android, cordova

I get following warning:

```
THREAD WARNING: exec()
 call to MyPlugin.setAndroidPreferences blocked the main thread for 49ms.   
Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
```

But from my code I use `cordova.getThreadPool()`:

```
private boolean setAndroidPreferences(
        final JSONArray args,
        final CallbackContext callbackContext)
{
    cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                /* ... */

                if ( /* ... */) 
                {
                    final SharedPreferences settings = cordova.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(preferenceLib, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
                    editor.commit();
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));                     
                } else {                                                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "getSetSharePreferences" + ": Error: " + PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            }
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

What Im doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @Fabii I have no clue but it might be function call. for me 48 msec is a lot even for generation Threadpool

Comment: ahh I see,  I ran into the same issue, it was more so of a warning; if I come across any viable solutions I'll let you know.

Comment: same problem here, getting the warning even using cordova.getThreadPool()

Answer (score 7):

According to [THREAD WARNING: exec() call blocked the main thread. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool(). – Cordova Plugin Warning](http://www.donmarges.io/thread-warning-exec-call-blocked-the-main-thread-plugin-should-use-cordovainterface-getthreadpool-cordova-plugin-warning/), try the following:

```
    public boolean execute(String action, final JSONArray inputs, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("setAndroidPreferences")) {
            cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(setAndroidPreferences(inputs));
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private PluginResult setAndroidPreferences(JSONArray args) {
        try {
            if ( /* ... */) {
                SharedPreferences settings = cordova.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(preferenceLib, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

                editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
                editor.commit();
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);                     
            } else {
                return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "getSetSharePreferences" + ": Error: " + PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulFacklam What did you change? I just don't see it.

Comment: I find the solution: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/578

Answer (score 0):

You must to use:

```
this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {...}
```

instead of:

```
cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {...}
```

Comment: Be careful in doing so, this will block the UI thread ... "If you do not need to run on the UI thread, but do not wish to block the WebCore thread either, you should execute your code using the Cordova ExecutorService obtained with cordova.getThreadPool() " https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html

Comment: After intense debugging I managed to extract the following error logs:

THREAD WARNING: exec() call to UniversalAnalytics.startTrackerWithId blocked the main thread for 34ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

and

THREAD WARNING: exec() call to OneSignalPush.init blocked the main thread for 64ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

I wonder what could be causing the freezing and Not Responding of the app and whether this is related to your query aswell. Did you come up with a possible work around to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Jan 2023 and still with this same problem for android. Any solution for this?
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/issues/578

Answer (score 0):

[reference source](https://www.boschrexroth.com/en/xc/products/engineering/opencoreengineering/engineering_network/forum/engineering_network_forum_1/-/message_boards/message/393470)

this is a known uncritical cordova warning which tells the plugin user,
 that everything slower than 50 ms should be called in an background thread.
 The OCI SDK is not using the cordova Thread-pool,
 instead it's using a background worker thread which has been changed to ExecutorTask for future releases.
 Your asynchronous connect() call is already executed in an background thread so it should not block your browser thread.
 But initialization and load mechanism of the OCI plugin (Java VM) could be the reason for a short time blocking.
 We added this issue for a detailed investigation of the blocking reason
 so we can prevent cordova to recognize this short hang situation in future.
 You can not prevent this warning in your code and have to ignore the warning.